# Unable to access a private function

Tags: c++, private-methods

```
 //**** Build of configuration Debug for project Calculator ****

   **** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\Calculator.o ..\src\Calculator.cpp
..\src\/Calculator.h: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, CComplex)':
   ..\src\/Calculator.h:38:9: error: 'float CComplex::m_imaginary' is private
  ..\src\Calculator.cpp:79:8: error: within this context
     ..\src\/Calculator.h:37:9: error: 'float CComplex::m_real' is private
   ..\src\Calculator.cpp:81:12: error: within this context
       ..\src\/Calculator.h:38:9: error: 'float CComplex::m_imaginary' is private
        ..\src\Calculator.cpp:81:31: error: within this context
     ..\src\/Calculator.h:37:9: error: 'float CComplex::m_real' is private
       ..\src\Calculator.cpp:85:12: error: within this context
         ..\src\/Calculator.h:38:9: error: 'float CComplex::m_imaginary' is private
       ..\src\Calculator.cpp:85:31: error: within this context
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 687  ms.
```

Can anyone help me - I am trying to access a private function which is not accepting the access.

Comment: So why are you trying to access a private function ? The above seems entirely expected

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it was otherwise, then this would have been an excellent question.

---

> When preceding a list of class members, the private keyword specifies
>   that those members are accessible only from member functions and
>   friends of the class. This applies to all members declared up to the
>   next access specifier or the end of the class.

The member function is not accessible because you are trying to access it from outside the class. As stated above, the private keyword is used to prevent exactly that.

If you do need access from outside the class then you need to make it a public method by using the public keyword.

Look here for [some examples and explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfbte35d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) regarding the private keyword.

---

Looking at you errors, i think the problem lies in your overloading of operator<< .
The operator can only be overloaded as a friend function, which by itself should solve your problem.

`friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, CComplex);`

Comment: You got the up because you made me laugh, and it is true :) but it isn't yet a complete answer. can you please extend your answer slightly, maybe explaining roughly to @harsha the difference between private/protected/public functions? Then you can keep the up ;)

Comment: @giorgio I was even tempted to upvote the question, but i had to stop myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make `operator<<` friend of the `CComplex` class. Something like this:

```
class CComplex {
    ...
    // It doesn't matter whether this declaration is on a private, 
    // public or protected section of the class. The friend function
    // will always have access to the private data of the class.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, CComplex);
};
```